# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm currently learning ASP.NET MVC apps. Basically I created a MVC 4 app with EF called Restaurant Review. However when I create a new review it shows an error. I know it must be something I missed.

The error is

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.ResturantReviews_dbo.Resturants_Resturant_Id". The conflict occurred in database "OdeToFoodDb", table "dbo.Resturants", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.**

Below shows my hierarchy.

Model

```
public class Resturant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string  Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResturantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class ResturantReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public int ResturantId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
    private readonly OdeToFoodDb _db = new OdeToFoodDb();

    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int restaurantId)
    {
        var restaurant = _db.Resturants.Find(restaurantId);
        if (restaurant != null)
        {
            return View(restaurant);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(int restaurantId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ResturantReview review)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Reviews.Add(review);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = review.ResturantId });
        }
        return View(review);
    }
```

View

```
@model OdeToFood.Models.Resturant

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Review For @Model.Name</h2>

@Html.Partial("_Reviews", Model.Reviews)
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new {restaurantId = Model.Id})
</p>
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create a review on a restaurant that doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you debugged into your `Create` method to make sure the `review.RestaurantId` contains a valid identifier?

Comment: Your `Create()` GET method is not passing the value of `restaurantId` to the view so when you submit the form, the value of `review.ResturantId` is `0` and therefore you get the error. And use a view model in your view, not the data model

Comment: And why in the world do you have `public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int restaurantId)`? If should be just `public ActionResult Index(int id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you `Id` property of your `Restaurant`  table is not unique or primary key. Please check that first and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with restaurants. Try to add checking if reviewed restaurants do exist. And also I am suggesting to add validation attributes for your models, like `[Required]`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by Entity Framework. Check if you have the Restaurant field inside your Review entity. If so, assign null to it before saving the Review (just leave the ID inside the RestaurantId field).

In some cases EF thinks that a detached entity is a new one (like if we are getting a Review with a Restaurant inside) and tries to add it to the database, getting an exception as exact same entity already exists. We have to prevent it from saving the Restaurant if we don't need it, so we should just save Review instead.

Also, as others mentioned, you might just add a review to the not-existing restaurant (not sure if it's the case for you, I suppose this kind of problem is easy to detect)

Let me know if it does/does not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property

```
public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
```

in `RestaurantReview` model class.

and Update-Database -Verbose in pakage manager console

Now build and run. It will solve the problem.